# C++ Need help for a homework program that reads in a list of doubles from a file and add a string to each double

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm having trouble with this homework program and now I'm stuck in what I should do. The program reads in a list of 12 doubles from a file. Each double represents the total rainfall in inches for the 12 months of the year in month order. The 12 doubles should be written into an array. The requirements are below.

This is the code that I have right now and I'm have no idea on what needs to go into the Function declarations `displayRainfall`, `bubbleSort`, and `swap` and what else needs to go into main:

```
// Headers
#include <iostream>     // cout, cin
#include <cstdlib>      // exit()
#include <string>       // strings
#include <fstream>      // file processing
#include <iomanip>      // stream manipulation
using namespace std;

// Global variables
const int MAX_MONTHS = 12; // months for rainfall
const string FILENAME = "TotalMonthlyRainfall2014.txt"; // The name of the file that is read

// Function declarations
int loadMonthlyRainfall (double rain[MAX_MONTHS], string fileName, int maxMonths);
void displayRainfall(string months[MAX_MONTHS], double rain[MAX_MONTHS], int monthCount);
void bubbleSort(double rain[MAX_MONTHS], int size);
void swap(int& a, int& b);

int main()
{
    int monthCount = 0;
    string months[MAX_MONTHS] = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };
    double rain[MAX_MONTHS];

    loadMonthlyRainfall(rain, FILENAME, MAX_MONTHS);   

    //  Make sure we place the end message on a new line
    cout << endl;

    //  The following is system dependent.  It will only work on Windows
    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}

int loadMonthlyRainfall(double rain[MAX_MONTHS], string fileName, int maxMonths)
{
    ifstream inFile;        // Input file stream
    int numMonths = 0;

    // Open file
    inFile.open(fileName);
    if (!inFile)
    {
        throw "Can not open file";
    }
    //
    for (int r = 0; r < MAX_MONTHS; r++)
    {
        inFile >> rain[r];
    }
    // Close the file
    inFile.close();

    for (int r = 0; r < MAX_MONTHS; r++)
    {
        cout << rain[r] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    return numMonths;
}

void displayRainfall(string months[MAX_MONTHS], double rain[MAX_MONTHS], int monthCount)
{

}    

void bubbleSort(double rain[MAX_MONTHS], int size)
{

}

void swap(int& a, int& b)
{

}
```

---

The program should do the following with the data:

1. Calculate the average rainfall for the year.
2. Determine which month had the lowest amount of rainfall.
3. Determine which month had the highest amount of rainfall.
4. Sort the array of rainfall in descending order (highest rainfall first) using a bubble sort.
5. Neatly display the average, minimum, and maximum rainfall. Be sure to display the month of the minimum and maximum rainfalls. Then display a table of month and rainfall amount from the sort.
6. Each of the monthly rainfall, average, minimum, and maximum 
   rainfalls should be displayed to two decimal places.

---

The output should look something like this:

```
Monthly Rainfall for 2014 

Minimum: September 0.06

Maximum: August 4.34

Monthly Average for Year: 1.77

Sorted by Total Rainfall

Month  Inches

August 4.34

May 3.40

June 3.26

November 2.13

October 2.09

April 1.74

March 1.45

December 1.13

July 0.98

February 0.41

January 0.33

September 0.06
```

Comment: *This is the code that I have right now and I'm lost on what to do:* -- **Exactly** what are you lost on?  Just saying "I'm lost" is not a focused question.

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: *Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, **and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.*** *I'm lost* is not a problem description unless you're asking a stranger for driving directions..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `bubbleSort(rain, MAX_MONTHS);` in `main` with these changes :

```
void displayRainfall(string months[MAX_MONTHS], double rain[MAX_MONTHS], int monthCount)
{
    //title
    cout << "Monthly Rainfall for 2014" << endl;

    //print minimum rainfall
    cout << "Minimum: " << months[MAX_MONTHS-1] << " "<< rain[MAX_MONTHS-1] << endl;

    //print maximum rainfall
    cout << "Maximum: " << months[0] << " "<< rain[0] << endl; 

    //get and print average rainfall
    double avg = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_MONTHS; i++)
    {
        avg+=rain[i];
    }
    avg = avg/MAX_MONTHS;
    cout << "Monthly Average for Year: " << avg << endl;

    //print ordered rainfall by month
    cout << "Sorted by Total Rainfall" << endl;
    cout << "Month" << setw(10) << "Inches" << setw(10) << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_MONTHS; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(10) <<months[i] << setw(10) << rain[i] << endl;
    }
}    

void bubbleSort(double rain[MAX_MONTHS], int size)
{
    string months[MAX_MONTHS] = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };
    //sort rainfall descending
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size - i; j++)
        {
            if (rain[j] < rain[j+1])
            {
                swap(rain[j], rain[j+1]);
                swap(months[j], months[j+1]);
            }
        }
    }
    //called inside bubbleSort because months and rain are sorted in scope
    displayRainfall(months, rain, 0);
}

void swap(int& a, int& b)
{
    int& temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
```